# Select last 5 elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Is it possible to select the last 5 child divs of an element?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Yes, you can get the div elements, and then use the `slice` method to get the last five:

```
var e = $('#someelement > div').slice(-5);
```

Answer (score 9):

Sure, you could use the `.length` property of a selector to get the count, and then use the `:gt(n)` selector to get the last 5.

```
var o = $("div.container > div:gt("+($("div.container > div").length-5)+")");
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.4 the `:gt()` selector is deprecated. `.slice()` is recommended

Answer (score 5):

As of jQuery 1.8, you can use a negative value in the `:gt()` pseudo selector.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector.

e.g.

```
var e = $('#someelement > div:gt(-6)');
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g4drety2/3/

**Notes:**

- The value needs to be `n+1`
- `.slice(-5)` is faster as `:gt` cannot use browser performance boosting.