# Select the last 3 child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know you can select the last child with `:last-child` or a certain child with `:nth-child` (if you know their position/number).

What I need is to select the last 3 children without knowing how many child elements there could be.

I know there is something that's called `:nth-last-child`  but I cant really understand how it is working.

For this:

```
<div id="something">

    <a href="images/x.jpg"  ><a/>
    <a href="images/x.jpg"  ><a/>
    <!-- More elements here -->
    <!-- ..... -->
    <!-- I need to select these: -->
    <a href="images/x.jpg"  ><a/>
    <a href="images/x.jpg"  ><a/>
    <a href="images/x.jpg"  ><a/>

</div>
```

I need something like this:

```
#something a:last-child{
   /* only now it selects the last <a> and the 2 <a>'s that come before*/ 
}
```

Comment: `:nth-last-child`, basically the same as `:nth-child` but counts from last to first afaik.

Comment: now the problem is it needs to select the last 3

Comment: P.S. Closing tags are `</div>` not `<div/>`.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can read more [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild) about nth-last child, but this should basically do the trick of selecting the last 3 children with just CSS

```css
#something a:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    /*declarations*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BV3K/) demonstration from **Fabrício Matté**

This will only select those rows returning a positive number for out N expression (-n+3), and since we are using nth-last-child, it's counting from last to first,
so first rows from bottom gives,

```
f(n) = -n+3
f(1) = -1+3 = 2 <- first row from the bottom
f(2) = -2+3 = 1 <- second row from the bottom
f(3) = -3+3 = 0 <- third row from the bottom
```

everything else will return a negative number

Comment: a -n this will of course  maken 3,2,1,0,-1 enz and so only selecting the last 3

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. I have been struggling for so long with this one.

Comment: Why not use nth-child(n+3) ? It seems more simple to me...

Comment: @avia because n+3 will select every element from 4 to the last element.
```f(n) = n+3
f(1) = 1+3 = 4 <- fourth element
f(2) = 2+3 = 5 <- fifth element
f(3) = 3+3 = 6 <- sixth element```

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with CSS3 selectors and [formulas](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/):

```
.something a:nth-last-child(-n+3) { ... }
```

You could also try [using jQuery (example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948152/select-last-5-elements-with-jquery) or adding a specific class to the last three elements in your server-side code (it does not require JavaScript to be enabled in browsers and also works on older browsers that do not support CSS3).

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer has the correct formula, but the explanation is wrong.

So the correct CSS is (same as currently accepted answer):

```
#something a:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    /*declarations*/
}
```

But here is the correct explanation of the math:

```
f(n) = -n+3
f(0) = -0+3 = 3 <- 3rd row from the bottom
f(1) = -1+3 = 2 <- 2nd row from the bottom
f(2) = -2+3 = 1 <- 1st row from the bottom
f(3) = -3+3 = 0 <- nothing
f(3) = -4+3 = -1 <- nothing
etc...
```