# 'slice' but only on certain class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It should slice the elements from the div with the class `.pagebreakable` from   `#bodytextp4` and insert them into `#bodytextp5`  if they dont fit and place them on the next page. Why does this code not work?

```
$('#bodytextp5').prepend($('#bodytextp4 div').find(".pagebreakable").slice(-1));
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? stackoverflow is not for finding people to do your work, but to help if you're stuck...

Comment: It was a trivial question. Perhaps you can all go down-vote this one too (which has far less effort shown): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948152/select-last-5-elements-with-jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bodytextp5').prepend($('#bodytextp4 .pagebreakable').slice(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.ol1').height() > 200){
    $('.ol2').append($('.ol1 li:gt(-3)'));
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g4drety2/2/

Note: Negative `:gt` values need to be n+1.

As `:gt` cannot take advantage of browser performance boosts, use `slice` for the fastest result:

```
if ($('.ol1').height() > 200){
    $('.ol2').append($('.ol1 li').slice(-2));
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/g4drety2/6/