# How do I change my JavaScript to run on page load instead of event change

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty running my JavaScript code on page load. I do not know enough about JavaScript to find the right option.

The code below works fine for a 'change' event, however I want the code to run at the time of loading and use the default values of the input fields to show the relevant divs.

I have tried changing the first line of the JavaScript to the following options with no success:

```
jQuery(document).ready('onload', e => {
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
```

Here is a fiddle to play with: **[JSFIDDLE >](https://jsfiddle.net/DSmit/ct1L9k8s/128/)**

**JavaScript :**

```
document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target.name == 'numberofdaysperchosenfrequency') {
    let parent = e.target.parentNode;
        parent.querySelectorAll('#daycol').forEach(n => n.style.display = 'none');
        
    if (e.target.value) parent.querySelector(`[data-id="${e.target.value}"]`).style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<strong>SET 01</strong><br>
<section>
<label>Days (enter value 1 to 6): </label>
<input type="text" name="numberofdaysperchosenfrequency" value="1">
<div data-id="1" id="daycol" name="day1col" class="hide">Day 1</div>
<div data-id="2" id="daycol" name="day2col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2</div>
<div data-id="3" id="daycol" name="day3col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3</div>
<div data-id="4" id="daycol" name="day4col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4</div>
<div data-id="5" id="daycol" name="day5col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5</div>
<div data-id="6" id="daycol" name="day6col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5 / Day 6</div>
</section>

<br><hr><br>

<strong>SET 02</strong><br>
<section>
<label>Days (enter value 1 to 6): </label>
<input type="text" name="numberofdaysperchosenfrequency" value="6">
<div data-id="1" id="daycol" name="day1col" class="hide">Day 1</div>
<div data-id="2" id="daycol" name="day2col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2</div>
<div data-id="3" id="daycol" name="day3col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3</div>
<div data-id="4" id="daycol" name="day4col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4</div>
<div data-id="5" id="daycol" name="day5col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5</div>
<div data-id="6" id="daycol" name="day6col" class="hide">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5 / Day 6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"I have tried changing the first line of the jQuery to the following options with no success"_ - all you are changing with that, is when the code that tries to add an event handler, runs. That doesn't change anything about the fact, that it is still a change handler - which will only execute, when the target element undergoes a change in value.

Comment: `jQuery:` - surprising lack of _anything_ jQuery in there :-) - this is plain, "vanilla" JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, you are absolutely right. I will change the question accordingly. This is part of a larger jQuery script hence my mistake.

Comment: Please note that you can't have muliple elements with the same id. ID must always be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have non-unique ID's for elements - jQuery will not work. Change ID to class.

Also remove any reference to event (since there is no such thing on DOM ready).

I have converted your JS code to actual jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.numberofdaysperchosenfrequency').each(hideDays);
  
  $('.numberofdaysperchosenfrequency').on('change', hideDays);
});

function hideDays() {
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.find('.daycol').show();
    parent
        .find(`.daycol:not([data-id="${$(this).val()}"])`)
        .hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>SET 01</strong><br>
<section>
  <label>Days (enter value 1 to 6): </label>
  <input type="text" class="numberofdaysperchosenfrequency" value="1">
  <div data-id="1" name="day1col" class="hide daycol">Day 1</div>
  <div data-id="2" name="day2col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2</div>
  <div data-id="3" name="day3col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3</div>
  <div data-id="4" name="day4col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4</div>
  <div data-id="5" name="day5col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5</div>
  <div data-id="6" name="day6col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5 / Day 6</div>
</section>

<br>
<hr><br>

<strong>SET 02</strong><br>
<section>
  <label>Days (enter value 1 to 6): </label>
  <input type="text" class="numberofdaysperchosenfrequency" value="6">
  <div data-id="1" name="day1col" class="hide daycol">Day 1</div>
  <div data-id="2" name="day2col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2</div>
  <div data-id="3" name="day3col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3</div>
  <div data-id="4" name="day4col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4</div>
  <div data-id="5" name="day5col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5</div>
  <div data-id="6" name="day6col" class="hide daycol">Day 1 / Day 2 / Day 3 / Day 4 / Day 5 / Day 6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Justinas, that's perfect. I wonder if you can assist with another question I have... If I wanted the value '2' to display 2 divs (i.e. data-id="1" AND data-id="2"), or 3 to show 3 divs, 4 to show 4 divs and so on... , how easy would it be to adapt this? or would I need to start from scratch? (I've a lot to learn!) :)

Comment: @DSmit So basically your `$(...)` selects array of elements. Then you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948152/select-last-5-elements-with-jquery)